# exception handling download stock data

Tags: python, finance

I want to download all the closing prices of the sp500 data and put into a dataframe. My exception handling is not catching.

I already tried the standard syntax exception handling

```
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr

import yfinance as yf
yf.pdr_override() # <== that's all it takes :-)


# NYSE
url_nyse = "http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-name.aspx?letter=0&exchange=nyse&render=download"
# Nasdaq
url_nasdaq = "http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-name.aspx?letter=0&exchange=nasdaq&render=download"
# AMEX
url_amex = "http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-name.aspx?letter=0&exchange=amex&render=download"

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(url_nyse)
stocks = df.index.tolist()


df_list = []
used_stocks = []

for stock in stocks:
    try:
        data = pdr.get_data_yahoo(stock, start="2017-01-01", end="2017-04-30")
        data_close=data['Close']
        df_list.append(data_close)
        used_stocks.append(stock)
    except ValueError :
        pass

df_list
```

I'm expecting stock index that are not available to be caught with the exception handling.

Answer (score 0):

You have at least 2 options.

The **first one** is to except every exception like this:

```
try:
    # your code
except:
    print "Caught it!"
```

The **second one** is to add every exception you encounter in order to change the behavior of your program accordingly.

```
try:
    # your code
except ValueError:
    print("Value Error")
except KeyError:
    print("Key Error")
```

Or like this if you don't want to handle them separately:

```
try:
    #your code
except (KeyError, ValueError):
    print("Error")
```

Comment: When I try your code. It does not catch the error. I get the following -[*********************100%***********************]  1 of 1 downloaded
[*********************100%***********************]  1 of 1 downloaded
Exception in thread Thread-36:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/andrewcz/miniconda3/envs/your_env_name/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/home/andrewcz/miniconda3/envs/your_env_name/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line